# Remote Desktop just displays desktop background color nothing else

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

Once in a while I will connect to Windows XP Pro via RDP, I will be logged on but the screen will just go to light blue - the color of the desktop background.  No windows are shown, no response to mouse or keyboard including ctrl-alt-end.  If another user logs in forcing me to log out then the next login is fine.  This seems to happen randomly.

Comment: That might be - but if you don't know the secret handshake it isn't going to be posted on serverfault by the person asking.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen it before too ... I think it has something to do with the screen saver.  I usually just close the session with the x on the RDP header bar and then re-establish the connection -- that seems to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

try reducing the colors to 16 bit or lower and turn off all the extras in the Remote Desktop connection settings.